# How to model two nodes related through a third node in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I'm learning Neo4j and currently whiteboarding the scenario i'm thinking of.
I have 3 products P1, P2, P3. P1 and P2 are standalone products. P3 is an adapter that helps you connect P1 and P2.

I thought of  `P1-[connects_to]-P2`, with P3 as a property of the `connects_to` relationship, but then how'd I store P3's properties?
if i create all three products as nodes and do `P1-[connects_to]-P3` and `P2-[connects_to]-P3`, that's not really representative of the domain.
How do i model this in Neo4j?

Comment: The adapter with the same properties connects only two products together? Or can be connected and other products together?

Comment: can be used for connecting other products together...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use a similar model:

```
(P1)-[:connected_through]->(A:Adapter)<-[:connected_through]-(P2)

(A)-[:type_is]->(P3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. you can also store properties on relationships
2. Why is creating P3 as a node and connecting it to the others not representative of the domain?
3. connects_to is a really bad non-descriptive relationship-type, find something in your domain that expresses that relationship better.

Comment: If P1 and P2 both connect to P3, it doesn't necessarily follow that P1 connects to P2, because those connections could be for connecting to some other product(maybe P4). Hence it's not representative of the domain.Understand that my example didn't really express this, so your question is quite valid.

Comment: (1) Guess I was trying not to have P3 as a relationship since it could be used for connecting many products together (eg. think of screw&nut).  (3) "I can connect P1 and P2, but you'd need a P3" is common-speak here-hence i picked it. Would be great if you could elaborate why it's bad and maybe that will give me a direction to think along!

Answer (score 1):

Have P1, P2 and P3 as nodes (since you said all 3 of them are products) and put P3 with a different label that identifies it as a connecting node.

Comment: Interesting idea,...Maybe I could store "From" and "To" as properties to express which two products are been connected by this instance of P3? Is that a bad idea?

Comment: If P3 will always connect no more than single pair of nodes (P1 and P2, for example), use directed relationship (P1) -> (P3) -> (P2). Later in your queries, you can easily identify which nodes enter into P3 and which leave from P3.

However, if P3 can connect a lot of pairs of nodes, you would have to rethink the design since it would be difficult to identify exactly which 2 nodes are getting connected by P3