# How to Model a relationship that adds a feature to a node?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is a follow-up to this earlier question
[How to model two nodes related through a third node in neo4j?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37415193/how-to-model-two-nodes-related-through-a-third-node-in-neo4j/37425402?noredirect=1#comment62392800_37425402)

If the capabilities of a product are enhanced by a `connects_to` relationship with another product, how should that fact be captured?

Example: given 
`(shelf:Shelf {maxload:20})`, if `(node:L-bracket)-[connects-to]->(shelf)`, then `shelf`'s `maxload` increases by 10.  Now, if someone queries for a `Shelf` that supports `maxload=30`, I should be able to retrieve this combination of `L-Bracket+Shelf` as an option, in addition to the shelves that support maxload without `L-bracket`. This is one use-case.

The other is when the `connects_to` relationship adds an entirely new property to the `Shelf` node. The option I'm thinking of is adding a property to the relationship called 'provides feature' and then query those as well when returning nodes, to see if a product is been enhanced by any of its connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part 1 :

> I should be able to retrieve this combination of L-Bracket+Shelf as
>   an option, in addition to the shelves that support maxload without
>   L-bracket.

This use case is handled with `OPTIONAL MATCH` :

```
MATCH (shelf:Shelf {maxload:30})
OPTIONAL MATCH (shelf)<-[:CONNECTS_TO]-(bracket:L-Bracket)
RETURN shelf, collect(bracket) as brackets
```

This would return you a list of shelfs and a collection of brackets for each of them - empty collection if they don't have any brackets.

Part 2 :

> the other is when the connects_to relationship adds an entirely new
>   property to the Shelf node. The option i'm thinking of is adding a
>   property to the relationship called 'provides feature' and then query
>   those as well when returning nodes, to see if a product is been
>   enhanced by any of its connections

You can simply use a `PROVIDES_FEATURE` relationship type, no need for a property on it. You can request for them in the same way as for part 1.

Answer (score 0):

To be a bit more general, suppose everything that can be connected to a shelf (not just an L-Bracket) was represented by an `Accessory` node that has `type` and `extraLoad` properties, like this:

```
(:Accessory {type: 'L-Bracket', extraLoad: 10})
```

This would allow accessories of different types and with differing extra load capacities.

With this model, you could find all `Shelf`/`Accessory` combinations that can hold a load of at least 30 this way:

```
MATCH (shelf:Shelf)
OPTIONAL MATCH (shelf)<-[:CONNECTS_TO]-(x:Accessory)
WITH shelf, COLLECT(x) AS accessories, SUM(x.extraLoad) AS extra
WHERE shelf.maxLoad + extra >= 30
RETURN shelf, accessories;
```